# Building Mono for ARM

Tags: mono

I am trying to get Mono to build for a custom ARM board that I am developing.  I have read the guide on the mono-project website (http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:ARM) a couple of times and I am still struggling with getting the environment setup to build.  I have searched the internet for get examples of setting up ScratchBox but I still haven't found one that makes sense to me (novice Linux user).  I know I am way over my head, but any pointers would be great appreciated as I am very eager to learn.

Comment: Please, describe the problems you are having. If possible post some console log, stack trace or error message you are having and the steps you have succeeded so far.

Comment: I am having a hard time getting ScratchBox setup, meaning I am not sure where to begin.  The link on the mono:ARM page to setting up scratch box is a dead link now and the easy installer link has no documentation that I could find.  I think once I get scratchbox setup I should be OK, but that is where I am struggling at the moment.

Comment: What is your OS type and version?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Linux 12.04, 32 bit.

Comment: Did you had any luck building Mono for ARM? I'm with the same problem setting up Scratchbox, no docs, nothing... Thanks

Comment: I have not been able to build it on my x86 machine yet, but I have been able to build it on my device.  Downloading the latest source and installing the build tools on the arm device worked for me.